# Fragments called multiple times on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm using simple `ViewPager` on my activity which with that i attach some fragments into that, when first fragment attached into that, the fragment called multiple

My simple code to test:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
    private ViewPager    pager;
    private PagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiate Pager & Adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() -1);
        }
    }

    // PagerAdapter SubClass
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage1();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage1();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

    } /* EOC */

    public static class TutorialPage1 extends Fragment {

        private static int pageIndex;
        private static final String TAG = "TAG";

        public TutorialPage1() {
        }

        public void TutorialPage1(int id) {
            pageIndex = id;
            Log.v(TAG, "Page Index is " + pageIndex); // this logs twice
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Res Index is " );
            ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "----->", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return rootView;
        }
    }
} /* EOC */
```

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

**#1**

In your getItem() call you have TutorialPage1() bring called on each case...

**#2**

ViewPagers do awaken the fragments on either side of them and store them in memory, in order to allow for quick switching between fragments, so that could be what you are seeing... but you can't verify unless you fix #1

Comment: yes, it is only test, after change it to other class, problem dont resolve sir

Comment: oh, i'm so sorry. please let me to test again